# Is it possible to install a provisioning profile without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, provisioning

I made an adhoc version of my iPhone app for a beta tester and he installed it on his device and everything was working fine. Yesterday, he got a message saying that the provisioning profile is about to expire in four days. He is on the road and doesn't have his computer with him so he can't sync his device with iTunes. Is there a way for me to send him a new provisioning profile to install on his device without the ability to sync to a computer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He can add a provisioning profile to his phone using the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&src=support_site.kbase.search&locale=en_US&q=iPhone%20Configuration%20Utility).  He will still need access to a computer that he can install it to, but he won't need to sync with iTunes.

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, as of iOS 4, you can add the provisioning profile without the use of a computer at all.  Check out [this article](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/).

Comment: @Chonch If Cory answered your question, you should accept his answer so he'll get credit for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything through the Organizer in XCode 4.
Once in XCode go to Window -> Organizer -> Devices and connect the iOS device you wish to install the provisioning profile on. Click "Add To portal" and the device will automatically get added to the portal and the provisioning profiles will get updated on the iOS device.